# join with latest records only from another table:- Remove replication

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 table lets say table1 and table2 `table 1` is the `master` data and `table 2` is `child`. I have to find out records from both table corresponding to the given `table1.id`. But there are more than 1 record in `table2` corresponding to `table1.id`. So I would like to filter the latest record first from `table2` corresponding to `table1.id` then apply the join on filtered data from table2 and table1.

```
table1= location_grids
table2= local_ads
```

Following what I am doing ?

```
SELECT  * FROM `location_grids`as l
LEFT JOIN `local_ads` la ON `la`.`location_grid_id` = `l`.`id`
Inner join (SELECT id, location_grid_id, max(booked_till) as maxbooked 
            from local_ads group by location_grid_id ) as b 
            on la. location_grid_id = b.location_grid_id 
            and la.booked_till = b.maxbooked
WHERE `l`.`location_id` =  '1'
AND `l`.`flag` =  1
```

The  query is returning me unfiltered data. How can I filter then apply join on data. Any help will be appreciated.

table1:- location-grid
[image]
table2:- local_ad
[image]

Comment: would you please provide data for table 1 and 2 along with what output you require in  tabular form !!

Comment: yes sure give me 5 mins

Comment: latest record ?? r u  storing any data insertion date or something in your table ? can u include table in the qstn ?

Comment: @AtulNar attached images are the snapshots of records.

Comment: These kinds of SQL questions are so incredibly common on StackOverflow, most users don't even bother to mark them as duplicates anymore. If only there was some way one could search the web for an answer before posting...

Comment: i create sample tables from your screenshots and executed your current query against it and it return single row with respect to Max(booked_till) and it seems fine.Whats your desired output ? you can also achieve this using simply `SELECT T1.*,T2.*,MAX(booked_till) FROM 
location_grids T1,local_ads T2
WHERE T1.id=T2.location_grid_id  AND T1.id=1438;`

Comment: @AtulNar: I wanted all records from location_grid and and their latest records only from local_ad.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution :- I was searching for following  query.

```
SELECT location_grid_id, user_id, booked_from, booked_till, purpose, category, duration, price, MAX( created ) 
FROM local_ads
GROUP BY location_grid_id
```

Here I wanted to run join with latest record of the particular id as many record must be exist in local_ads